# How does Bash deal with brackets inside of double quoting?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, sh, double-quotes

The question is basically, how does bash deal with double quotes and brackets?

I couldn't come up with a better example, so apologies about that, but imagine something like this:

`"$(echo "${foo}")"`

What happens there? Is `${foo}` technically out of the quotation scope? Is bash smart enough to also consider that it is inside of the parentheses and work inside-out? Would `\"${foo}\"` work better?

I've tried Googling this, but no luck. Please note that this is different from just nested quoting questions, as it includes expansion.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling that you are understanding it wrong. Can you clarify your point of view?

Comment: I want to prevent word-splitting. Twice. So the example that I shown is part of a more complicated command invocation.

I.e. I want the result of `$(echo ${foo})` to be interpreted as one word, but also ${foo} should be interpreted as one word. 

This is mostly out of curiosity for how bash escaping works, not that I can't work around this by e.g. temporary variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each command substitution establishes a new quoting context, so the correct way to avoid word splitting inside nested command substitutions is to use double quotes.

In this example, white space is preserved:

```
$ echo "$(echo "$(echo 'foo     bar')")" # outer echo sees 'foo     bar'
foo     bar
```

However, missing any of the double quotes means that the string is split by the shell:

```
$ echo $(echo "$(echo 'foo     bar')") # outer echo sees 'foo' 'bar'
foo bar
$ echo "$(echo $(echo 'foo     bar'))" # middle echo sees 'foo' 'bar'
foo bar
```

`echo` outputs each argument, separated by a spaces, which is where the single space between "foo" and "bar" comes from.

Comment: What an (this will not be correct word of choice but) programming-answer!  absolutely amazing! 

Praise!

Answer (score 3):

The example you gave **does** save you from word splitting completely:

```
"$(echo "${foo}")"
```

while,

```
"$(echo ${foo})"
```

would save you from word splitting on the output but not on the variable `$foo`.

`$()` opens a subshell and you need to quote your vars in this subshell too. Consider the following example:

```
"$(echo "$(echo "$foo")")"
```

None of the pair of quotes above is optional, if you miss any of them, you will be subject to word splitting.

Consider another example:

```
"$foo var in same shell, $(cmd) - this output is also in the same shell"
```

In above, `$foo` and the output of `cmd` are safe, but if the cmd includes another variable inside `$()`, then that variable will need to be quoted.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I meant, but the other answer came first :/ sorry.

Comment: @Santiago it's not a race; you should choose whichever answer you prefer and upvote the ones that are helpful to you.

Answer (score -2):

What is foo? Is it a value? try

```
"$(echo "$\{foo\}")"
```

Comment: What do you mean value? If you mean a variable, then yes. 

Any reason you put escaping before brackets and not quotes? See my other comment for clarification:

I want to prevent word-splitting. Twice. So the example that I shown is part of a more complicated command invocation. I.e. I want the result of $(echo ${foo}) to be interpreted as one word, but also ${foo} should be interpreted as one word. This is mostly out of curiosity for how bash escaping works, not that I can't work around this by e.g. temporary variables.

Comment: @Snow can you please (try) (or if not; PM me and I can help formulate your answer if you want) try - try to elaborate ; and write more (I.e include references, I guess-do-not-answer-the-question-with-a-question,  (IF it is MEANT this way- IF NOT I do apologize!)